# How to change header of bootstrap4 django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I defined the table as below

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap4.html"
        model = Mymodel
        attrs = {"class": "table table-hover"}
```

I want to change the table head to make  appear light or dark gray, [like this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#table-head-options).

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
attrs = {
        'class': 'table table-hover',
        'thead' : {
            'class': 'thead-dark'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not explicitly in the docs, but judging from how it describes to set `th` attributes from the Table.Meta.attrs property this is how you do it:

```
    attrs = {
        'class': 'table table-hover',
        'thead' : {
            'class': 'head-dark'
        }
    }
```